# Prove or disprove Let $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ for every $x < 1$. Then $\lim_{N\to\infty} R_N(-0.5)$ = $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Prove or disprove Let $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ for every $x < 1$.  Then $\lim_{N\to\infty} R_N(-0.5)  =  0$. I know that instead of $x$ we can set $t$ =$-x$ then we get a known Taylor series, so we know that we can derive  $f(x)$  $N$ times and use Taylor polynomial ($T_N$) to calculate the limit of $R_N$ with the formula $R_N(x) =  f(x) -T_N(x)$ but when I try to calculate $T_N(-0.5)$ it equals to $\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{f^{(n)} (0) (-0.5)^n}{n!}$ but I don't know how to continue. There is a mistake here? What is the motivation to solve it?

Comment: its an entire series with convergence radius $=1$, so the rest will always converge to $0$ for $|x|<1$

Comment: @OrFinberg Do you know the error estimate for the remainder term?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Even if the series converges there, it is in general not true that the series represents the function in any way. Here the OP is asked to prove exactly that.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I did not see that the OP did not have this background. Better use Taylor (integral version then). What I said was valid if he knew about entire series.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I am not quite sure what you mean. Knowing that the function is analytic surely yields that the error term goes to zero, but even if the OP showed that the corresponding Taylor series converges (is that what you mean by entire series?), it does not tell us that the $R_N$ goes to zero, unless we already knew that $f$ is analytic.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven sorry, mistranslation from me, I meant power series :) but of course the OP does not have this info yet I was dumb

Answer (score 1):

You did no mistake but the Taylor series of $f$ is more easily calculated and bounded this way:$$\frac1{1-t}-\left(1+t+\dots+t^{N-1}\right)=\frac{t^N}{1-t}$$
hence for $0\le x<1,$
$$\begin{align}0&\le-R_N(x)\\&=-\left(\ln(1-x)+x+\frac x2+\dots+\frac{x^N}N\right)\\&=\int_0^x\frac{t^N}{1-t}dt\le\frac{x^{N+1}}{1-x},\end{align}$$
which converges to $0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: good clear answer +1